# Class RTCCVPixelBuffer is implemented in both, One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined

Tags: swift, class, webrtc, swift4, rtcc

I have an issue with dependencies included in Class RTCCVPixelBuffer.

I am using OpenTok SDK in my iOS App. When I try to run the app, I get a console full of error like :

> Class RTCCVPixelBuffer is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/Frameworks/libwebrtc.dylib (0x11d0aa160) and /Users/PrakharBhardwaj/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/973561FB-0A4E-4D10-82C8-BC447940DD34/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/786DB5B1-EC67-49EF-B6A9-FFC7E2FFEC90/EvueMe.app/EvueMe (0x109690c70). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Here are the contents of my podfile:

```sh
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'evueme' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for evueme
pod 'OpenTok'
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably related to this [WebRTC bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=187653).

Comment: So what we do now?

Comment: We currently have an app in production and everything works fine (even if the console prints these errors) but in the next weeks I will try to use a newer version of the WebRTC framework.

Comment: The problem is also tracked here https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=10560

Comment: In the end I kind of solved it: I've changed the prefix for every classes defined in the iOS sdk and then compiled the WebRTC framework; no more console errors.